# Usage of adjective solus

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice, syntax, adjective, sentence-translation

I'm trying to translate the sentence "The whole state was thanking this man's brother alone." (that is, the brother the only one being thanked)
My try is: *Tota civitas fratri huius soli gratias agebat*.

I wonder if my usage of *soli* (as dative) is right. (I think *solus* must follow the case of *fratri*, which is dative. Am I correct?)

I'm teaching myself Latin with Wheelock's Latin, and this is a sentence given as an exercise in CAPVT IX. I used *civitas* because it is the only word meaning 'state' until CAPVT IX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your translation is correct, apart from missing the word *viri*.

"The whole state was thanking" is indeed translated well with *Tota civitas gratias agebat*.
The expression *gratias agere* requires dative to indicate who is thanked.
Therefore if you want to thank "this man's brother" (*frater huius viri*), the dative expression you need is *fratri huius viri*.
The genitive *huius viri* ("this man's") does not change.

The exact translation of "alone" depends on what it refers to.
The most natural interpretation is that it refers to the brother, whence *solus* takes the gender and case of *fratri*.
The singular masculine dative is *soli* — note that *solus* is declined like *unus* rather than like *bonus*.
(The genitive would be *solius*.)
This leaves us with this translation: *Tota civitas fratri huius viri soli gratias agebat*.

If you wish "alone" to refer to the man (whose brother is being thanked), switch *solus* to the same form as *huius viri*.
The singular masculine genitive is *solius*.
Thus you get: *Tota civitas fratri huius viri solius gratias agebat*.
I doubt this was intended, though.

(An earlier version of the question mentioned that *soli* was genitive. This is why I added some emphasis on its declination.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understood the structure of the sentence.